# Getting weird characters from conversion of char to TCHAR

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, type-conversion, win32gui

I'm getting really weird characters from the conversion. Any idea why? I get the "data" from an external device and i need to display it to win32 GUI. It had no problem when i

```
printf("%s\n",data);
```

in the console mode but having trouble when i migrate it to win32 which requires me to convert to TCHAR to display.

```
CHAR data[256];
TCHAR data1[256];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,MB_COMPOSITE,data,-1,data1,0);   

CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), data1, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD |
                  10, 50,300,300,hWnd, (HMENU) none, NULL, NULL);
```

By the way, using

```
hDLL=LoadLibrary("MyKad.dll");
```

in win32 couldn't work so I had to used

```
hDLL=LoadLibrary(TEXT("MyKad.dll"));
```

May I know is this right? Thanks

Comment: Win32 does not require `TCHAR`. You're better off using wide strings.

Comment: Is your project an UNICODE project ?

Comment: Wanted to submit an answer but my reputation is less than 10. So I'll insert it here.

Ok, I think the default settings for win32 project is Unicode. Hence, bringing alot of problems to me because I initially coded everything in MultiByte in windows console project. So by just changing the Project-> Properties-> Configuration Properties->General and changing the character set to multibyte. everything was solved. I changed for active and release mode.

Comment: Your reputation is now 13, you can answer your own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your code fails is that you pass `0` in the final parameter of `MultiByteToWideChar`. You can fix your code by passing the length if `data1`:

```
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_COMPOSITE, data, -1, data1, 256);
```

Note also that you should be checking for errors when calling API functions. Had you done so you would have discovered that `MultiByteToWideChar` was failing.

I use the following function to convert to UTF-16:

```
std::wstring MultiByteStringToWideString(const std::string& MultiByte,
    const UINT CodePage)
{
    std::wstring result;
    int cchWideChar = MultiByteToWideChar(CodePage, 0, MultiByte.c_str(), -1, 
        NULL, 0);
    if (cchWideChar > 0)
    {
        wchar_t* bufferW = new wchar_t[cchWideChar];
        if (MultiByteToWideChar(CodePage, 0, MultiByte.c_str(), -1, bufferW, 
            cchWideChar) != 0)
        {
            result = std::wstring(bufferW);
        }
        delete[] bufferW;
    }
    return result;
}
```

So you could use this as follows:

```
std::wstring windowName = MultiByteStringToWideString(data, CP_ACP);
CreateWindow(L"STATIC", windowName.c_str(), ...);
```